# receive data from buffer in socket programming

Tags: port, sockets, client-server

please see this picture. recvfrom() blocks until a datagram is received from a client. Since there is no connection,each datagram may come from a different sender.

[image]

i can receive data form receiver but i dont know how server can find which data is for which client? because it is possible 8.8.8.8 client send 3 datagram and server have to sort data.do server allocate specific buffer for each client?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to design the protocol so that the message includes some kind of source identifier. Failing that, you can use the source IP address and port to determine the client, though that will break if the client's IP address changes.

Comment: dear David if linux allocate a buffer for each process i think we dont have any problem.but when we have one buffer all things is difficult....i want to recognize each client data .what is your idea????????????

Comment: @m-tech I suggested two ideas. One: Have the client include some kind of identifier in the datagram. Two: Identify the client by the source IP address and source port of the datagram.